# CDF of a learned distribution doesn't evaluate

Tags: probability-or-statistics

In this simple example

```
z={0., 0.0512821, 0.0909091, 0.0952381, 0.191489, 0.242424,0.276596, 0.27907, 0.347826, 0.465116, 0.487179, 0.5, 0.555556}

pdf=LearnDistribution[z]
Plot[PDF[pdf, z], {z, -.5, 1}]
```

[image]

the distribution is learnded quickly.

But the cumulative distribution  `CDF[...]`

```
CDF[pdf, .5]
```

doesn't evaluate!

What's wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the documentation states "LearnDistribution[examples] yields a LearnedDistribution[ ... ] on which the following functions can be used:"; that list does not include `CDF` as one of the functions.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you, I have read over it !

Comment: With a fresh kernel I get a `LearnedDistribution` with a `Method: KernelDensityEstimation` but any subsequent running of the code I get a `Method: Multinormal` just as you show.  (Windows 10, Mathematica 12.3.0)  I'm just in general distrustful of such black boxes.